# Convert dataframe objects to float by iterating over columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert data in Pandas.Series by iterating over Series

DataFrame df looks like

```
   c1   c2
0  -    75.0%
1 -5.5% 65.8%
.
n  -    6.9%
```

'%' and '-' only values should be removed. Desired result:

```
   c1    c2
0  0.0   75.0
1 -5.5   65.8
.
n  0.0    6.9
```

If I call

```
df['c1']= df['c1'].str.replace('%', '')
df['c1']= df['c1'].str.replace('-%', '0')
df['c1']= df['c1'].astype(float)
```

it works.

But if I try to iterate it does not:

```
col= [] 
col.append(df['c1'])
col.append(df['c2'])

for i  in (col):
    i = i.str.replace('%', '',regex=True)
    i = i.str.replace('-$', '0',regex=True)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you try the code that does not work?

Comment: Nothing is happen, no change at the data. There comes no error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Improved regex

```
# Thanks to @tdy
df.replace({'\%':'', r'^\s*-\s*$':0}, regex=True)
```

Explanation - Since string-based data can often have random spaces. also you can just replace it with 0 since the subsequent float conversion will handle the decimals.

**Output**

```
    c1      c2
0   0.0     75.0
1   -5.5    65.8
2   0.0     6.9
```

**Explanation**

We can use regex over complete df, to replace the required symbols, we are replacing `%` with empty string and if a row consists of `-` at the end then replace it with 0.0.

Comment: i suggest improving Bernd's regex from `r'-$'` to `r'^\s*-\s*$'` since string-based data can often have random spaces. also you can just replace it with `0` since the subsequent float conversion will handle the decimals.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. But the question remains why the for loop has no result as expected.

Comment: Same behavior for changing df[col] = df[col].astype(float) inside for loop. Is there a way to change object type for a bunch of columns but not for whole df?

Comment: That might be because of 'for loop scoping'. You can easily get info about it online.